# Build Server for Android APK using Azure

Tags: azure

I'm trying to build an APK dynamically using JAVA and ANT, using windows azure infrastructure. I think i have two options, cloud services and virtual machines. The virtual machine options comes with a lot of headache, setup java and ant on a linux image, and set up apache as the front facing server to receive the requests.

I prefer using the cloud services, but how can i install JAVA and ANT on a cloud service. I can include ant as a folder in my project structure, but java does not look installed on the cloud service machines, how can i include JAVA as well, and is this the right thing to do for what im trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TBH your requirement really sounds right for a persistent Virtual Machine and not a Cloud Service which can be recycled / rebuilt at any time. Cloud Services only run Windows so you'd need to script the install of Apache (assuming IIS wouldn't suit), Ant and the appropriate JDK.  I'd just bake it once as Linux VM, create an image and then schedule power up / down of the VM when required.

Comment: yea u have a point, but my main project is running on a cloud service already so im trying to use it for the build server as well. I couldnt find any articles discussin how to install java or ant in a cloud service, is it doable? iis is fine for now don't need to change anything

Comment: You would need to use startup tasks on the role to install Ant and the JDK using an 'unattended' model where no manual input is required.  MSDN has detail on the use of Startup Tasks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh180155.aspx